# How to iterate through a vector that is part of a struct?

Tags: c++, struct, iterator

I have the following two structs that I use to define a line:

```
struct Point{
    double x;
    double y;
};

struct Line {
    unsigned int n_points;
    std::vector<Point> points;
};
```

I would like to iterate through the `points` vector after adding some data. I tried

```
int main(){
    Line line;
    // add some data to points vector with `push_back`

    // print content of `points`
    iter = line.points.begin();
    for(; iter != line.points.end(); ++iter){
        std::cout << iter.x << " " << iter.y << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This, however, does not work. Can someone explain me why?

Comment: *How* it does not work? You get compiler error? Incorrect output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is syntax error in your code. Assuming you defined the type of `iter` before or you can use: 
`auto iter = line.points.begin();`

Here, `iter` is a type of an iterator. A `.` operator won't work & you need to use `->` operator just like pointers as follows:

```
auto iter = line.points.begin();
    for(; iter != line.points.end(); ++iter){
        std::cout << iter->x << " " << iter->y << std::endl;
    }
```

You can refer here for more information http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail why the `.` operator won't work?

Comment: @random9 `iter` is of type iterator. Using `.` you can access members of the iterator class. If you want to access object that iterator points to, you need to use `->` or dereference is first: `(*iter).x`

Answer (score 4):

You only have syntax errors in your example. Fixed:

```
int main(){
    Line line;

    //vvv added auto
    auto iter = line.points.begin();
    for(; iter != line.points.end(); ++iter){
        //           vvvvvvv iter->x instead of iter.x. Same for iter.y
        std::cout << iter->x << " " << iter->y << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However, with modern C++, you can do the same more easily:

```
int main() {
  Line line;

  //            vvv make a reference if that matters
  for (auto const [x, y] : line.points) {
    std::cout << x << ' ' << y << '\n';
  }
}
```

This version uses the [Range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) and [Structured binding declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) features from C++11 and C++17 respectively.